# Worker Takes A Break After Completing Its Task (Released)

Tags: arena-simulation

I am currently working on a problem where a worker must take a 10 minute break after completing its task.

The number of workers is 20 so I set the resource capacity as 20.
The first process is set as 'Seize Delay'.
The worker is released after the third process.

[image: Process Flow]

I created a failure in the Failure module based on count, where the Count is set as 1, and Downtime is set as 10 minutes. This means when 1 worker is released it will be down (taking a break) for 10 minutes.

[image: Failure Module]

The problem with this approach is that Arena applies the failure to the entire resource, not just one capacity.

Is there anyway I could work around that so that the failure is applied to only 1 capacity or simply the number of busy workers is increased by one for just 10 minutes after the worker is released?